# All Possible Jordan Canonical Forms Given Characteristic Polynomial

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form

I am given the characteristic polynomial $x^2(x^2-1)$ and am asked to find all possible jordan canonical forms.  What I have so far is:

Possible elementary divisors are: 1) $x,x,(x+1),(x-1)$, 2) $x,x,(x+1)(x-1)$, 3) $x^2,(x+1)(x-1)$, and 4) $x^2(x+1)(x-1)$.  I therefore got the possible Jordan forms as:

1)=2) \begin{matrix}
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1
        \end{matrix}

and

3)=4)
\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1
        \end{matrix}

I'm really unsure if these are correct, so any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The use of the term *elementary divisors* suggests you're looking for a way to relate JNF with smith normal form. Is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are correct. What the characteristic polynomial $$x^2(x-1)(x+1)$$tells you is that there are at least $3$ cages, of which the cages for eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ have size $1$. This only leaves the eigenvalue $0$, for which you have $2$ options:

1. There are $2$ linearly independent eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $0$. In that case, your matrix has $4$ eigenvectors and can be diagonalized.
2. There is only $1$ linearly independent eigenvector for $0$. This means that the cage for $0$ is $2\times 2$ and the Jordan form is as your second matrix suggests.

Of course, all this is done up to permutation, meaning that you can change the order of the eigenvalues on the diagonal and still get a Jordan form.

Comment: While basically correct, you should avoid saying "there are $2$ eigenvectors...". There are always infinitely many eigenvectors.

Comment: How about "$2$ linearly independent eigenvectors"?

Comment: Corrections noted. Thank you.